# How to store a login path for psql?

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres instance on Amazon RDS and I want to store the login path so I don't have to remember the host name/username/password to log in each time. In mysql I can simply create a login_path. Is there a postgres equivalent I'm not seeing. What is a common approach to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OS environment variables or setup the `pgpass` configuration file

Set the values for the following OS envvars:

```
PGHOST, PGPORT, PGDATABASE, PGUSERNAME, PGPASSWORD
```

Or, do it in a file:

In Windows, create/edit the file `%appdata%\postgresql\pgpass.conf`

In Unix-like systems it's `~/.pgpass`

And add the following info in this format:

```
hostname:port:database:username:password
```

Restart your shell and you're good to go.